# How to create CrossTab in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I used AWS sagemaker linear learner and generate such a prediction result;

```
enter code here

{'predictions': [{'predicted_label': 1.0, 'score': 0.1817770004272461},
{'predicted_label': 1.0, 'score': 0.1815681904554367},
{'predicted_label': 1.0, 'score': 0.17859019339084625},
{'predicted_label': 0.0, 'score': 0.17681272327899933},
{'predicted_label': 0.0, 'score': 0.17504917085170746},
{'predicted_label': 0.0, 'score': 0.17504917085170746}}
```

and I have original test data as

244    0
245    1
246    0
247    0
248    0
249    0

How can I format a crosstab?